# Branch.io Unpopulated vs Unattributed (Organic)

Tags: branch.io

I am learning how to use Branch.IO and I was wondering with respect to installs, what is the difference between an unpopulated install vs organic install?

I understand that organic means the install isn't attributed to a click or impression, but then what does unpopulated mean? If an install was due to a click or impression, wouldn't it have the corresponding ad as a source?

Thank you very much.

Answer (score 0):

A Branchster here -

For a particular device with unique device identifier values remaining constant, Branch measure an INSTALL event as the first app open.

The INSTALL or any other [event](https://help.branch.io/developers-hub/docs/tracking-commerce-content-lifecycle-and-custom-events) could be either be organic(unattributed) or attributed. Unpopulated on Dashboard reporting refers to the values which are not set.

For example, if you are comparing data as per Campaign/Channel and see Campaign as Unpopulated -
[image]

Then the above depicts that Campaign value was not set for this particular Ad. Similarly, if you see `channel` as Unpopulated, then you might have a Quick Link/Ad Link without the channel value set.